# Spring Data Redis Expire Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, redis

I have a Spring Hibernate Application. In my application, Recently i am implemented Spring data Redis.

```
spring-servlet.xml
<!-- redis connection factory -->
<bean id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:use-pool="true"/>

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" 
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnFactory"/>
```

And this `redisTemplate` use in my ServiceImpl class.

```
RedisServiceImpl

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate;

public RedisTemplate<String, T> getRedisTemplate() {
    return redisTemplate;
}

public void setRedisTemplate(RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
}
```

Now I added data in redisServer like this

```
public void putData(String uniqueKey, String key, Object results) {
        
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(uniqueKey, key, results);
}
```

Now i want to remove Expire key.

I search in Google, But in google all are saying like this

```
redisTemplate.expire(key, timeout, TimeUnit);
```

In this expire method, We need to provide `uniqueKey` instead of `key`.
But I need to Expire `key` instead of `uniqueKey`.

So Please help me what can i do for expire `Key`?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#expire(K,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) Doesn't say anything about a uniqueKey. You can pass the key to expire

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this url doesn't say anything about uniqueKey. But In implementation when i use uniqueKey then this uniqueKey is expired. But when i use key then this key is not expired.

Comment: The unique key is considered for the whole hash... so can expire the key for this hash. Unless you need to remove the hash key and value manually.

Answer (score 20):

I am using Spring Data Redis.

I am using `@Redishash(timeToLive=300)` annotation to expire my Entities after 300 seconds.

Here is the excerpt from my `pom.xml`

```
...
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
...
```

My `RedisConfig.class`

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackageClasses = ConsentOTP.class)
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        log.info("=================================================================");
        log.info("redis config : {} : {} ", host, port);
        log.info("=================================================================");

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
        config.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }

}
```

And my entity class `ConsentOtp.class`

```
@RedisHash(value = "ConsentOTP", timeToLive = 300)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConsentOTP implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1708925807375596799L;

    private String id;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private String otp;

    public ConsentOTP(String personId, LocalDateTime timestamp, String otp) {
        this.id = personId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.otp = otp;
    }
}
```

Here is my Redis repository

```
public interface ConsentOtpRepository extends CrudRepository<ConsentOTP, String> {
    
}
```

Comment: this solution adds phantom keys in Redis and other app like python reading these keys will get two values for same key(1 orignal and 1 phantom)...

Comment: Yes it does add a phantom key. But  it wont be a problem if one is accessing the store from Spring boot or the likes.

Answer (score 12):

I am using Redis Version 3.2.100.

Instead of **redis template** ,Use **Redis Cache Manager**, pass redistemplate to cacheManager and use its  set expires property to which is basically map of String & Long  , you can add cache name and set its expiry time i.e time to live (TTL).

You can use **setDefaultExpiration** method of cacheManager to set same expiry time to all the cache.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unused" })
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, order = 1)
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class CacheConfigImpl extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    private @Value("${redis.ip}") String redisHost;
    private @Value("${redis.port}") int redisPort;

     private static final Map<String, Long> cacheMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    static {
        cacheMap.put("method1cache", 600L);
        cacheMap.put("method2cache", 600L);
        cacheMap.put("method3cache", 800L);
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(CustomPropertyLoader.getProperty("redis.ip"));
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(CustomPropertyLoader.getProperty("redis.port")));
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "RCacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {

        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        cacheManager.setExpires(cacheMap);
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        final String redis_client_name = CustomPropertyLoader.getProperty("redis.client.name");
        cacheManager.setCachePrefix(new RedisCachePrefix() {
            private final RedisSerializer<String> serializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
            private final String delimiter = ":";

            public byte[] prefix(String cacheName) {
                return this.serializer
                        .serialize(redis_client_name.concat(this.delimiter).concat(cacheName).concat(this.delimiter));
            }
        });
        return cacheManager;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually you can do it with [Redisson](https://redisson.org) Redis Java Client using `RMapCache` object. It provides ability to set `ttl` and `maxIdle` per map entry. Example:

```
// implements java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap interface
RMapCache<String, SomeObject> map = redisson.getMapCache("anyMap");

// ttl = 10 minutes, 
map.put("key1", new SomeObject(), 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// ttl = 10 minutes, maxIdleTime = 10 seconds
map.put("key1", new SomeObject(), 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually You cannot expire or set the TTL for individual keys inside the Redis Hash. You can only expire or set TTL the complete hash. if you want to support  this you have to change your data structure.

Here is the link for why it is not possible; and below are some excerpts from 
[Redis expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire)

> As far as i know redis cares for performance than features. It will
>   defeat the purpose of memory efficient hash implementation in redis.
>   Since hash key-value fields are not always represented as full
>   featured redis object (they could be stored as linear array when hash
>   is small to save memory), so the hash key field cannot have a TTL.

Also this link [Allow to set an expiration on hash field](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1042) might help you to change your data structure to handle expiry

Answer (score 5):

To set TTL for keys, you may create multiple beans of cacheManager and set TTL for individual bean. Then as per your use, you can use required cachemanager.
Here is what I have implemented.

```
@Configuration("cacheConfig")
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport{


    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println("redisConnectionFactory");
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

        // Defaults
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
        System.out.println("redisTemplate");
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager cacheManager2(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(20);
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        return cacheManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager1(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(60);
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        return cacheManager;
    }

}
```

To use above created cachemanager beans,

```
@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#userId.toString()", cacheManager ="cacheManager2")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
        LOG.info("Getting user with ID {}.: "+userId);
      return userService.fetchUserDataonUsers(userId);
    }


@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#userId.toString()", cacheManager ="cacheManager1")
    @RequestMapping(value = "data/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserData(@PathVariable String userId) {
        LOG.info("Getting user with ID getUserData {}.: "+userId);
      return userService.fetchUserDataonUsers(userId).toString();
    }
```

when we define `cacheManager ="cacheManager2"` in  `@Cacheable` , It will use TTL set for `cacheManager2` defined in configuration. Same goes for `cacheManager1`

Answer (score 3):

You can adopt Quartz for this purpose (implementing ttl for a Redis record).
If you use Spring Boot, it autoconfigures [Scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz) for you. Thus you can autowire it directly to your service layer.

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;
```

Then you need to implement a job like this (in this example I am using Spring Redis Data):

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RemoveExpiredRecordJob implements Job {

@Autowired
public RedisRepository redisRepository;

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
    String key = jobExecutionContext
            .getJobDetail()
            .getKey()
            .getName();
    redisRepository.deleteById(key);
    log.info("Record removed due timeout :: {}", key);
}
```

}

Then you can encapsulate some logic for creating JobDetail and Trigger

```
@Component
public class SchedulerComponentBuilder {

    public JobDetail getJobDetail (String key, Class<? extends org.quartz.Job> clazz) {
        return JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(clazz)
                .storeDurably(false)
                .withIdentity(key)
                .withDescription("This key will be removed from Redis store when time expires.")
                .build();
    }

    public Trigger getTrigger(int ttl, JobDetail jobDetail) {
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, ttl);
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                .withDescription("This trigger fires once to remove an expired record from Redis store.")
                .startAt(calendar.getTime())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And finally, right after you saved you record in Redis repository, you need to schedule a job for removal this record (uniqueKey) from it like this:

```
@Autowired
private SchedulerComponentBuilder schedulerComponentBuilder;

private void schedule(String uniqueKey, int ttl) {
    try {
        JobDetail jobDetail = schedulerComponentBuilder.getJobDetail(uniqueKey, RemoveExpiredRecordJob.class);
        Trigger jobTrigger = schedulerComponentBuilder.getTrigger(ttl, jobDetail);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,jobTrigger);
        log.info("Job is scheduled :: {}", jobDetail);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        log.error("Filed to schedule a job {}", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though I am late to the party posting this for the Posterity.

Setting `TTL` value in key level it is not possible, because `org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager` does not provide any methods to configure the TTL value in key despite they have provided it for the `cache` level. The following steps will help you configure the TTL time in a `cache` and `default` level.

1. Adding required maven dependency.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. adding Redis configuration including TTL values for default level and cache level. Here we have set the TTL value to a sample cache called "photo".

```
cache:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  default-ttl: 6000
  caches-ttl:
    photo: 3600
```

3. Adding RedisCacheManager configuration

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Autowired
    private CacheConfigurationProperties cacheConfigurationProperties = null;

    private org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration createCacheConfiguration(long timeoutInSeconds) {
        return org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Map<String, org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
        if (Objects.nonNull(cacheConfigurationProperties.getCachesTTL())) {
            for (Entry<String, String> cacheNameAndTimeout : cacheConfigurationProperties.getCachesTTL().entrySet()) {
                cacheConfigurations.put(cacheNameAndTimeout.getKey(), createCacheConfiguration(Long.parseLong(cacheNameAndTimeout.getValue())));
            }
        }
        return RedisCacheManager
                .builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(createCacheConfiguration(Long.parseLong(cacheConfigurationProperties.getDefaultTTL())))
                .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(cacheConfigurationProperties.getHost());
      redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(Integer.parseInt(cacheConfigurationProperties.getPort()));
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache")
    @Data
    class CacheConfigurationProperties {
        private String port;
        private String host;
        private String defaultTTL;
        private Map<String, String> cachesTTL;
    }
}
```

The complete documentation is available at [Medium](https://medium.com/@prasanth_rajendran/caching-with-spring-boot-data-redis-84aa49d15595)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Difference was just in using Jedis client. I solved it changing postions of UniqueKey and Key.
For your example it will be something like this:

```
redisService.sadd(key, uniqueKey);
redis.expire(key, expirationTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for @Akanksha Sharma's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056326/4367032) with Lettuce redis client.

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379));
}

@Bean
@Primary
public CacheManager cacheManager1(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    
    return RedisCacheManager
            .builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(60L)))
            .build();
    
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager2(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    return RedisCacheManager
            .builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1L)))
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure if this is still active but the only correct answer is provided by

Santosh Joshi

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896731/4222461

as he correctly states you cannot expire an individual key in a redis hash, only the hash itself.

see https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/1042

and https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/1042#issuecomment-45367109 in particular

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short : via RedisConnection

```
public void saveInCache(String key, Object obj) {

    RedisConnection connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        connection.set(key.getBytes(), SerializationUtils.serialize(obj));
        //setting custom expiry runtime
        long expiresIn = obj.getExpiresAfter() - Instant.now().getEpochSecond(); 
        connection.expire(key.getBytes(), expiresIn);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle any exception
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while closing redis connection : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```