# Redisson eviction on set/map

Tags: java, spring, redis, redisson

I don't understand how eviction work on set with Redisson.

Thanks to [the wiki](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections#731-set-eviction), i can see there is an `org.redisson.EvictionScheduler`. This worker is supposed to schedule execution to evict old keys in Redis. This method is used to apply TTL on sub-element of a list, and not globally on the key holding the list in Redis. (The TTL on the key list is set to `-1` by the way)

I can't make this work, the scheduler doesn't seem to execute. Do i have to create some more bean on the spring conf ? Is there any additional things to do ?

I'm using a RSetCache.

to put a value : 
`redisson.getSetCache(key, stringCodec).add(value, lifeSpan, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`
so i'm using this method : `org.redisson.api.RSetCache#add`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expired Redisson Keys still visible in Redis Cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824834/expired-redisson-keys-still-visible-in-redis-cli)

Comment: please see my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824834/expired-redisson-keys-still-visible-in-redis-cli/46838604#46838604

Comment: I'm not using a `RMapCache`but a `RSetCache`. I edited the post.
By the way, I can see a "score" field associated with the value in the list in Redis. Is it the `ttl` or the eviction date ?

Comment: The same logic applies to RSetCache too.